# Event Brite api timezone issue

Tags: php, eventbrite

Have been trying to create new event via EB API call, confronted the issue of date validation...
https://www.eventbrite.com/json/event_new?app_key=xxxxxxx&status=live&user_key=xxxx&title=greatword2&description=green&start_date=2013-05-02+5:00:00&end_date=2013-05-30+00:01:00&timezone=GMT+01
As i am sending the above call, regardless of the timezone passed, start date is validated as per GMT-7 timezone(California perhaps)....
is there a way to fix this? as we are dealing with clients from across the globe, just cant ask them to match with again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Note, I work on the platform team at Eventbrite
```

The timezone string you are using is not the correct format.  The `GMT\d` format is quite old, and the code ignoring it and defaulting to `America/Los_Angeles`.  For GMT you would pass in `Etc/GMT`.  It looks like you are +1 GMT in which case you'd use something like `Europe/Warsaw`.  No matter what you provide, it should be the actual timezone name.

You can read more here:

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_new/